# Inequality with the constraint $xy=x+y$

Tags: inequality, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have to prove that if $x$ and $y$ are two positive numbers such that $xy=x+y$, the following inequality
$$\frac{x}{y^2+4}+\frac{y}{x^2+4}\geq \frac{1}{2}$$
holds. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Think you for edited

Comment: $\left(~x > 0\ \mbox{and}\ y = {x \over x - 1} > 0~\right) \implies \left(~x > 1\ \mbox{and}\ y > 1~\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac{(x+y)^2}{4}\geq xy=x+y$, we obtain $x+y\geq4$.

Thus, by C-S $\frac{x}{y^2+4}+\frac{y}{x^2+4}\geq\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy^2+x^2y+4(x+y)}=\frac{x+y}{xy+4}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{x+y}}\geq\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality is not true for $0<x,y<1.$  $x,y$ must be greater than $1.$

Answer (score 0):

By renaming $x$ as $\frac{1}{u}$ and $y$ as $\frac{1}{v}$ we have to prove that $u,v>0$ and $u+v=1$ grant
$$ \frac{u^2}{v+4u^2 v}+\frac{v^2}{u+4uv^2}\geq \frac{1}{2} $$
that is the same as showing that for any $x\in(0,1)$ the inequality
$$ \frac{x^2}{(1-x)(1+4x^2)}+\frac{(1-x)^2}{x(1+4(1-x)^2)} \geq \frac{1}{2} $$
holds. That is almost trivial since $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)(1+4x^2)}$ is a convex function on $(0,1)$, hence
$$ f(x)+f(1-x) \geq 2\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} $$
as wanted.